# Significance/Purpose of %1$s in javascript string?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Can someone explain what just happened here?

```
console.log("She has done her wizarding course %1$s and is presently working %2$s", "from HOGWARTS", "in MOM");
//She has done her wizarding course from HOGWARTS and is presently working in MOM
```

How %1$s got replaced in javascript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Outputting_text_to_the_console

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Firefox. Given that `console.log` is not-standardised, it's likely an implementation detail of the environment you're using. For the record, This is `printf`-like syntax for replacing placeholders.

Comment: you only have to use%{number} if you are not passing substitute values in order.
you can simply do this ```console.log("She has done her wizarding course $s and is presently working $s", "from HOGWARTS", "in MOM");``` %{number} represent what value will go where  %1 means first value %2 means 2nd value and so on.

Comment: thanx guys figured it out